# Python: Embed a matplotlib plot with slider in tkinter properly

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have created this plot in pyplot which has a slider to view a certain range of the data.

```
import random
import matplotlib
import tkinter as Tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

y_values = [random.randrange(20, 40, 1) for _ in range(40)]
x_values = [i for i in range(40)]

l, = plt.plot(x_values, y_values)
plt.axis([0, 9, 20, 40])

ax_time = plt.axes([0.12, 0.1, 0.78, 0.03])
s_time = Slider(ax_time, 'Time', 0, 30, valinit=0)


def update(val):
    pos = s_time.val
    ax.axis([pos, pos+10, 20, 40])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
s_time.on_changed(update)

#plt.show()

matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

root = Tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in TK")

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

Tk.mainloop()
```

The problem is, it seems unresponsive when embedded in a tkinter window, although when I show it with plt.show() (meaning the code after this, is commented) works correctly. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured this one out. The figure needs to be added to the canvas before creating the plot.

```
import random
import matplotlib
import tkinter as Tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

root = Tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in TK")
fig = plt.Figure()
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

y_values = [random.randrange(20, 40, 1) for _ in range(40)]
x_values = [i for i in range(40)]

ax.axis([0, 9, 20, 40])
ax.plot(x_values, y_values)

ax_time = fig.add_axes([0.12, 0.1, 0.78, 0.03])
s_time = Slider(ax_time, 'Time', 0, 30, valinit=0)


def update(val):
    pos = s_time.val
    ax.axis([pos, pos+10, 20, 40])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
s_time.on_changed(update)

Tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Been trying to figure out how to do something like this for two days. Thanks.

Comment: @fishbacp Happy to help. I remember this driving me crazy for days...