# How to embed contourf into tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, contourf

We have some discussions about embedding a matplotlib with slider in tkinter

[Python: Embed a matplotlib plot with slider in tkinter properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325321/python-embed-a-matplotlib-plot-with-slider-in-tkinter-properly)

The key part is the following codes

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

root = Tk.Tk()
root.title("Embedding in TK")
fig = plt.Figure()                       
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)     
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)
```

My question focuses on 'contourf'.

```
X = np.arange(1,5,1)
Y = np.arange(1,5,1)
x , y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)  
z = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    ]    
conto = plt.contourf(x,y,z)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(conto,root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0, row=1, pady=15, sticky=tk.W)
```

The above is what I tried to do; however, an error popped out

```
AttributeError: 'QuadContourSet' object has no attribute 'set_canvas'
```

Is there any way for 'contourf', like canvas, such that we can embed contourf into tkinter?

Comment: Please add a [mre] to your question and take the time to explain what you have tried and how it behaves differently from your expected outcome.

Comment: @Thingamabobs Thanks! I tried to modified my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example mixed between the offical [exampel of matplot in tkinter](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html) and a [random youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3YhcrXq8cVQ). It works fine for me:

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Embedding in TK")

fig = plt.Figure()                       
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)     
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
u = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
x,y = np.meshgrid(u,u)
z = x**2 + y**2
ax.contourf(x,y,z)
```

Comment: When I ran it on Jupyter Notebook, it shows"<matplotlib.contour.QuadContourSet at 0x2c4e8b10ca0>". No GUI window popped out.

Comment: add root.mainloop() at the end.