# How to insert view function into a Tkinter frame?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, jupyter-notebook, fuzzy-logic

I have been following this tutorial: https://pythonhosted.org/scikit-fuzzy/auto_examples/plot_tipping_problem_newapi.html

And now I am trying to create a GUI, I have done everything without problem, but I have not been able to get the view function to be displayed in the same window, it is executed in a new one.
This is the line I would like to insert inside a frame:

> propina.view(sim=simul_propinas)

This is how it currently looks:
[Tkinter Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0NHG.png)

How can I make it show inside?

Comment: You need to use a canvas inside your `tk.Frame` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70469200/how-to-embed-contourf-into-tkinter)

Comment: Thanks! But they create it from scratch, I already have the data in the function, it is drawn with this line tip.view(sim=simul_tips). I tried to create a Canvas object, but I don't know how to insert it inside it. Im newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into the source code of `scikit-fuzzy` module, `propina.view()` is defined as below:

```py
def view(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """""" + FuzzyVariableVisualizer.view.__doc__
    fig, ax = FuzzyVariableVisualizer(self).view(*args, **kwargs)
    fig.show()
```

So you can combine the above code with the example on [Embedding in Tk](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html) to embed the plot into the required tkinter `Frame`:

```py
...
#matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
matplotlib.use('Agg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
...
def calcular():
    ...
    # don't call propina.view(...)
    #propina.view(sim=simul_propinas)

    fig, ax = ctrl.visualization.FuzzyVariableVisualizer(propina).view(sim=simul_propinas)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=framegraficos)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
    canvas.draw()
    ...
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Very Useful, Next time I'll be more observant.

Answer (score -3):

It is basically not possible... You can try it out with PyQt5 it will be way easier, and your problem and be fixed with PyQt5.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I saw on youtube that someone did it, but I didn't see how, and now I can't find that video.