# (Python) My slider cannot work in FigureCanvasTkAgg

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, slider

I try to design a simple slider in the following environment; however, it cannot work

Note: I use Jupyter Notebook, so I utilized FigureCanvasTkAgg and TkAgg.

Note: I referred to the following great discussion; however, it still cannot work.
[Python: Embed a matplotlib plot with slider in tkinter properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325321/python-embed-a-matplotlib-plot-with-slider-in-tkinter-properly)

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib widget
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

root = Tk()
root.title('TEST')
root.geometry("800x800")

def plot_noise():
    fig = plt.Figure()                       
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)     
    canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=3, rowspan=3, sticky=W+E+N+S, padx=0, pady=0)  
    slider_bar = fig.add_axes([0.12, 0.1, 0.78, 0.03])
    slider_de = matplotlib.widgets.Slider(slider_bar, 's_bar', 0, 124, valinit=20)

ttk.Label(root,text = "Push the Button", font=('Arial', 25)).grid(column=0, row=0, ipadx=5, pady=5, sticky=W+N)  
resultButton = ttk.Button(root, text = 'show', command = plot_noise)
resultButton.grid(column=0, row=1, pady=15, sticky=W)

root.mainloop()
```

However, the slider cannot work. I mean I cannot move the slider (no error pops out.)

How to fix that?   Thanks!

[image]

Comment: *it cannot work* is a real broad discription of your issue. What does not work and how you did plan to make this happen? As I see it the code does exactly what it should do. What are you missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Embed a matplotlib plot with slider in tkinter properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325321/python-embed-a-matplotlib-plot-with-slider-in-tkinter-properly)

Comment: @Thingamabobs 1. The slider cannot move, which is my problem here.  2. My code just referred to the link you provided. The only difference is I just preserve the codes of slider.

Comment: and where is your `update` function then ? There are no instruction for `Slider.on_changed(function)`, so there will be no change made.

Comment: @Thingamabobs That function is not necessary actually. I just double checked that. If you delete that function, the slider can still work.

Comment: My bad and I'm sorry. I have provided an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/ac2a14581949bcf869e969f28a21ee479d2fc250/lib/matplotlib/widgets.py#L234) I have found your issue:

> """
> The base class for constructing Slider widgets. Not intended for direct
> usage.
> For the slider to remain responsive you must maintain a reference to it.
> """

The problem is that your Slider get garbage collected. You can prove that by:

```
    global slider_de
    slider_bar = fig.add_axes([0.12, 0.1, 0.78, 0.03])
    slider_de = matplotlib.widgets.Slider(slider_bar, 's_bar', 0, 124, valinit=20)
```

Also see the [report of this bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3105/) and the given [explaination in the docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/event_handling.html):

> The canvas retains only weak references to instance methods used as
> callbacks. Therefore, you need to retain a reference to instances
> owning such methods. Otherwise the instance will be garbage-collected
> and the callback will vanish.

and the reason for this architecture is also found in [the source](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/ac2a14581949bcf869e969f28a21ee479d2fc250/lib/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py#L159):

> In practice, one should always disconnect all callbacks when they are
> no longer needed to avoid dangling references (and thus memory leaks).
> However, real code in Matplotlib rarely does so, and due to its design,
> it is rather difficult to place this kind of code.  To get around this,
> and prevent this class of memory leaks, we instead store weak references
> to bound methods only, so when the destination object needs to die, the
> CallbackRegistry won't keep it alive.